# Não consigo acessar um índice de um array

Tags: python, array

Bom, eu estou com problemas ao acessar o 3° índice da minha lista. Quando eu tento acessar, me retorna um erro de: **List index out of range**.

```
vertices = [[-1,-1,1],
            [-1,1,1],
            [1,1,1],
            [1,-1,1]]

for v in vertices:
  print(v[3])
```

Eu quero acessar os vértices, 1,-1,1. Porém eu sempre me deparo com este erro.

Comment: Os índices de cada v vão de 0 a 2 nesse seu exemplo. O que você espera que tenha no 3?

Comment: `[1,-1,1]` está em `vertices[3]`, não `v[3]`. O `v` é cada uma das listas internas, com 3 números cada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo os valores que você deseja receber... Você deve substituir o índice de acesso  aos valores do vértices, de 3 para 0.

Este erro (List index out of range) acontece pois você está tentando acessar um índice que não existe.

Em algumas linguagens de programação (ex: Python, PHP, C#, Java), os índices começam no 0. Sendo assim, a representação dos índices do vértice seria assim:

```
índices:    0   1  2     0  1  2    0  1  2    0   1  2
vértice: [[-1, -1, 1], [-1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, -1, 1]]
```

Note que o índice 3 não existe, neste caso.

Código:

```py
vertices = [[-1, -1, 1],
            [-1,  1, 1],
            [ 1,  1, 1],
            [ 1, -1, 1]]

for v in vertices:
  print(v[0])
```